# What are different time-series types?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, moving-average

I am having a time-series classification problem. I tried to using `movingaverage` and `firstdifferences` as two models to perform my classification. However, the results I am getting are pretty bad.

Therefore, I am thinking whether there are any other types of time-series data that I can use instead (i.e. instead of movingaverage`and`firstdifferences`). If so please suggest me.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: I do not think these are classification models. How did you classify time series with them?

Comment: @RichardHardy I use LSTMs to classify my timeseries :)

Comment: Why do you need moving averages or first differences then? Or are they a part of LSTM and you are wondering about the specification of LSTM? (Probably a stupid question since I am not all that familiar with LSTM.)

Answer (score 1):

Both of the "models" that you listed are particular types of ARIMA models where one series exists and one wishes to use the history of the series to generate a forecast. Examples of this are here [Forecasting/predicting total sum of donations (following GLM with poisson family and log link)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438217/forecasting-predicting-total-sum-of-donations-following-glm-with-poisson-family/438224#438224) and here [Help me about using ARIMA forecasting rainfall](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438241/help-me-about-using-arima-forecasting-rainfall/438256#438256)  .

If you wish you can post one of your data sets (must be equally spaced in time) and I will try and help further.  The methodology underlying model identification is briefly introduced here. [How to interpret PACF?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438235/how-to-interpret-pacf/438273#438273)    .